# Customer direct login not working

Tags: magento-1.9, error, login

Customer login is not working (apart from on checkout)
We get this response:

Fatal error: Call to a member function isAllowedGuestCheckout() on a non-object in

```
/home/multiweb/public_html/online-lighting-outlet.co.uk/app/design/frontend/default/hellononino/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml on line 43
```

We are not sure what coding to put in.

Many thanks

This is the code:
?>

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer onepage checkout login form template
 *
 * @see app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
 */
/** @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Login */
?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('login_before')?>

<div class="block block-checkout-register">
    <div class="block-title">

    </div>
    <div class="block-content">

        <?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Register with us for future convenience:') ?></p>
        <?php else: ?>
        <p><strong><?php echo $this->__('Register and save time!') ?></strong><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('Register with us for future convenience:') ?></p>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->__('Fast and easy check out') ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->__('Easy access to your order history and status') ?></li>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
        <ul class="form-list">
                   <?php if( $this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ): ?>
            <li class="control">
                <input type="radio" name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" /><label for="login:guest"><?php echo $this->__('Checkout as Guest') ?></label>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li class="control">
                <input type="radio" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register"<?php if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()==Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER || !$this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif ?> class="radio" /><label for="login:register"><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Register and save time!') ?></h4>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Register with us for future convenience:') ?></p>
        <ul class="ul">
            <li><?php echo $this->__('Fast and easy check out') ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->__('Easy access to your order history and status') ?></li>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" checked="checked" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="required">&nbsp;</p>
            <?php if ($this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout()): ?>
            <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
            <?php elseif ($this->helper('checkout')->isCustomerMustBeLogged()): ?>
            <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/url')->getRegistrationUrl();?>'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
            <?php else: ?>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('persistent/index/saveMethod'); ?>">
                <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="submit" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
            </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="block block-checkout-login">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">

        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
        <form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getPostAction() ?>" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <h4><?php echo $this->__('Already registered?') ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $this->__('Please log in below:') ?></p>
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <li>
                        <label for="login-email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="login-email" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="login-password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry" id="login-password" name="login[password]" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                </ul>
                <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div class="buttons-set">
            <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot your password?') ?></a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    $('login-email').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
    $('login-password').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
    function bindLoginPost(evt){
        if (evt.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
            loginForm.submit();
        }
    }
    function onepageLogin(button)
    {
        if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
            button.disabled = true;
            loginForm.submit();
        }
    }
//]]>
</script>
<?php
    $registerParam = $this->getRequest()->getParam('register');
    if ($registerParam || $registerParam === ''):
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
            if($('login:register')) {
                $('login:register').checked = true;
                checkout.setMethod();
            }
        })
    //]]>
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can you please show code of  logging?

Comment: where you have put this code ,i,e i mean in which page?

Comment: I haven't put this code in, it is the default template for hellononio login.phtml

Comment: in which page? screen shot please

Comment: sorry this system will not let me add a screen shot, put the problem is on the following page: http://online-lighting-outlet.co.uk/customer/account/login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joanne,isAllowedGuestCheckout function is  only work when you  have call login from at checkout.

There are may be some in your code:

If this  called at checkout then you was call wrong template.

According to link.

Your phtml page code is wrong.So copy code from

```
base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
```

ans past here:

```
default/hellononino/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
```

Comment: I have attached the full code, just so you are aware we have disabled the shipping quote form, will this be the reason it is not working?